# Discord python slash commands dynamic choices

Tags: python, discord.py

Is there a way to dynamically generate the list of choices in discord slash command options based on guild_id?

Say for example if the `guild_id == 123` then generates 3 choices, however, if the `guild_id == '456'` then generates different choices, in this case, the choices keys/values are pulled from config file that is read by the `Config` class.

```
@slash.slash(
    name="verify",
    description="Verify token Ownership",
    guild_ids=[Config.guild_id],
    options=[
        create_option(
            name='token_type',
            description='Choose what you want',
            required=True,
            option_type=2,
            choices=[
                create_choice(
                    name=Config.token_type_name_1,
                    value=Config.token_type_value_1
                ),
                create_choice(
                    name=Config.token_type_name_2,
                    value=Config.token_type_value_2
                )
            ]
        )
    ]
)
async def slash_verify(ctx:SlashCommand, token_type:str):
    pass
```

Comment: I think discord.py dont have this function but you can code your own function to do that.